# pandas to_numeric a large wide dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need to apply `pd.to_numeric` to a long and wide (1000+ columns) dataframe where invalid values are coerced as NaN.

Currently I'm using

```py
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
```

which can take substantial amount of time due to the number of columns.

```py
df.astype()
```

does not work either as it does not take `coerce` option.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using pyspark? may help you.

Comment: @tornikekharitonishvili any reference for this specific task?

Comment: How many columns and rows do you have?  shape

Comment: 6million * 1000

Comment: Of course, you should use pyspark for such quantities. It is faster than Pandas on big data.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been commented on, the amount of data you're working with makes it pretty hard for pandas transformations to **not** be extremely slow.
I recommend you set up a PySpark session inside your local machine, transform the DataFrame column types and proceed to convert to Pandas at the end if you really need it.

In PySpark, you can convert all your dataframe's column to float by doing this:

```
df = df.select(*(col(c).cast("float").alias(c) for c in df.columns))
```

Afterwards you can just save your DataFrame back to where you want it to be (or maybe stick to PySpark and join the group!):

```
df.toPandas().to_csv('my_file.csv')
```